# OpenID Connect AAD user impersonation

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I've implemented authentication based on the OpenID Connect sample found [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore). In development environment I'd like to add user impersonation which also works with on behalf of authentication. I want downstream APIs like the Graph API or other services like Azure Analysis Services to use the impersonated user too.

Where can I read up on how to implement this? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Where can I read up on how to implement this? Is this even possible?

It is possible to implement this using OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of (OBO) flow.

Detailed documentation from Microsoft is available here:

[Service to service calls using delegated user identity in the On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow)

[image]

> The OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of (OBO) flow serves the use case where an
>   application invokes a service/web API, which in turn needs to call
>   another service/web API. The idea is to propagate the delegated user
>   identity and permissions through the request chain. For the
>   middle-tier service to make authenticated requests to the downstream
>   service, it needs to secure an access token from Azure Active
>   Directory (Azure AD), on behalf of the user.

Your current sample that you've already implemented has taken care of the green part in picture above. Following the instructions in shared link for OBO you need to implement the remaining part. "Web API B" will be the downstream API like Graph API or others that you will call using delegated user identity from the first Web API (i.e. Web API A in your already implemented sample).

Comment: This is not impersonation, this is delegation. It's clearly stated in doc you copy/pasted: "The idea is to propagate the delegated user identity and permissions through the request chain"